# What should I do after accepting my husband's oath not to take tea from me?

Tags: oaths

My husband asked me to accept his oath that he wouldn't take tea from me.  As I was angry, I said yes, but now he blaming me for accepting his oath. But my point is that no one should accept someone else's oath by asking someone. What should I do?

Comment: Was the swear taken by any of the unique names of Almighty Allah (e.g. Allah) or a name that when uttered reminds of Him only?

Answer (score 2):

> [Making an oath, also known as *swearing an oath*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swear)
>
> [An **oath** [...] is either a statement of fact or a promise [...]](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Oath&oldid=581157582)
>
> [A **promise** is a commitment by someone to do or not do something.](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Promise&oldid=553889433)

In your case you swore to an action that will not be performed by *you* but by someone else which by definition is meaningless, therefore the rules of [vow/oath](http://www.sistani.org/english/book/48/2379/) will not apply.

But if you mean that you husband swore, which cannot be read from the question in it's current state, not to take tea from you after you said *yes* even then I don't think the rules of vow wouldn't apply because:

- the oath was involuntary but rather influenced by your decision
- most probably was taken in a state of excitement
- the act should be normal or usual to sensible people, or to the person himself.

Now says the vow was valid meaning the above criteria are not met, then your husband has to give Kaffarah/penalty/compensation by either:

- setting free a slave
- fully feeding ten indigent/poor people, or providing them with clothes
- or if the above isn't possible then he should fast for three consecutive days

Source: [Ayatollah al-Sayyid 'Ali al-Husayni al-Sistani](http://www.sistani.org/english/book/48/2380/)